# How to set laravel app on Digital Ocean under docker?

Tags: docker, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I installed laravel 5 app on Digital Ocean Server (under kubuntu 18) using Docker
So now url of mysite looks like
`http://NNN.NN.NNN.N:8085/public/login`, where
http://NNN.NN.NNN.N - is ip of my server
8085 - port I set in docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

    web:
        build:
            ...
        ports:
            - 8085:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
```

I want to include youtube video for this app, so I have to set client ID/ client secret and getting 
Authorized redirect URIs I have to enter Authorized domains value like :

```
NNN.NN.NNN.N:8085
```

I got error message  :
Invalid domain: cannot contain port.

Can you give me a hint how to salve this task?
have I to use new domain for this app, like https://my.freenom.com
But how to work with it as I have port set ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**
I remade my project files:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

    web:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER =#1000
            - VIRTUAL_HOST    =my.freenom.com
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - 8085:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}


    db:
        image: mysql:5.5.62
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql


    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8086:80
        links:
            - db


    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

web/Dockerfile.yml :

```
FROM nginx:1.10

 RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libpng-dev  \
     nano  libmcrypt-dev 

 RUN docker-php-ext-install \
     pdo_mysql \
     mcrypt \
     && a2enmod \
     rewrite
```

but running command :

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

I got error :

```
 docker-php-ext-install: not found
```

Could you please to look at files syntax above?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have something running on Port 80 of the host? Can you not just do a port mapping to port 80 such as --> ports: -80:80

Comment: I am not sure, but I would prefer not to take port 80 and left it free. Some other decisions ?

Comment: Have you checked out this link from digital ocean? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Or this blog post has a docker file--> https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NGINX as a reverse proxy server (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), and add an env-var called "virtual-host" to the container as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 80808:8080 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=my.freenom.com --name web your_image
```

or on your docker compose case

```
version: '3.1'

services:

web:
    build:
        ...
    ports:
        - 8085:80
    env:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST: my.freenom.com
    working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
```

then configure a DNS to point to the machine ip, Once you have done that any requests matching the virtual host will be redirected to the container on the exposed port.

Comment: Thankl you for your feedback!
That seems direction I need.Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: @mstdmstd if this answer help you considere marking it as valid, anyway, for the block #2 that's a separate question that you should raise, a short recommendation is to use docker network instead of link because link is deprecated, also you need to use the volume specified in the docs for the nginx container.